# Refreshing multiobject object with static variables inside

Tags: c#, events, multiple-instances, updating

I should see it, but I don't...
I have a class that changes the mode of a device and contains some graphic self-instantiated buttons. For this, I need to implement the class, BUT probably there would be more than one instance of that class.

I create the class and set a static variable `MODE` so that it would be only one of this in all the objects I will instantiate (ALL will refer to this static variable to know what the mode is).
When the mode change I have an event that raises and send to the ''main'' the value of the mode actually chosen.
I can't make a singleton NOR a static class because I have some design object as a button for my instantiated object. I need to be able to have two more objects in two form with the design from my class, but I need them to be synchronously refreshed when the mode change (for example the button name change to mode3).

So my problem is: I need another event inside my class to be able to refresh all the objects instantiated.
So two events are sent to my ''main'' and it's not clean. 
How could I do it to send only one time an event and refreshing my objects at the same time?

Some code :

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    changeMode newmodeclass;
    changeMode newmodeclass2;
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        newmodeclass = new changeMode();
        newmodeclass2 = new changeMode();
        changeMode.e_ModeChanged += new EventHandler<changeMode.Mode_Args>(changeMode_e_ModeChanged);//static event to permit the change of all the objects created
    }
    private void changeMode_e_ModeChanged(object sender , changeMode.Mode_Args e)
    {
        label1.Text = e.refreshed.ToString(); 
    }
}

class changeMode
{
    public static event EventHandler<Mode_Args> e_ModeChanged;//EVENTS FOR OUTSIDE
    public class Mode_Args : EventArgs//events args (selected MODE)
    {//return arguments in events
        public Mode_Args(Int16 ivalue) { refreshed = ivalue; }//ctor
        public Int16 refreshed { get; set; }//accessors
    }

    private static event EventHandler RefreshMode;//EVENT FOR REFRESHING MY OBJECTS

    private static Int16 _ActualMode = 2;//MODE3=3, MODE2=2 or OTHERS=4 ACTUAL MODE AS STATIC
    public Int16 ActualMode//MODE ACCESSOR
    {
        get { return _ActualMode; }
        set
        {
            switch (value)
            {
                case 2:
                    _ActualMode = 2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    _ActualMode = 3;
                    break;
                default:
                    _ActualMode = 4;
                    break;
            }
            if (e_ModeChanged != null) { e_ModeChanged(this, new Mode_Args(_ActualMode)); }//EVENT FOR OUTSIDE
        }
    }
    public changeMode()//ctor
    {
        RefreshMode += new EventHandler(FObj_MdiAuto_RefreshMode);
    }
    protected virtual void FObj_MdiAuto_RefreshMode(object sender, EventArgs e)//RECALL actualmode accessor (which do the work twice)
    {
        ActualMode = _ActualMode;
    }
    protected virtual void bt_ChooseMode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//on click change mode
    { 
        if (_ActualMode==3) ActualMode = 2;
        else ActualMode = 3;
        RefreshMode(this,EventArgs.Empty); //call event for refreshing all others object created   
    }
}
```

How could I refresh without this internal event??

Hope you understand my problem, thanks all!!

Comment: Somebody here? I need help please. It's easy but I m too far insidw.